# How to sort the table by date if the date is not filled everywhere?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, react-table

** not working:**

I am using react-table, what am I doing wrong?
I am currently using version 7 of the plugin.

```
 {
        Header: 'DATE',
        accessor: 'DATE',
        sortType: (rowA, rowB) => {
            const a = rowA.values.DATE;
            const b = rowB.values.DATE;

            if (a !== null && b !== null) {
                const dateA = getDate(a);
                const dateB = getDate(b);

                if (dateA === dateB) {
                    return 0;
                }

                if (dateB > dateA) {
                    return 1;
                } else {
                    return -1;
                }
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        },
    },
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve] such as codesandbox

Answer (score 0):

You are returning `0` when even one of them is `null`. You could first `sort` based on whether the dates are null. Move the nulls to the end. Then, sort them based on the actual date value (Assuming `getDate` returns Date objects)

```js
sortType: (rowA, rowB) => {
  const a = rowA.values.DATE,
        b = rowB.values.DATE;

  return (a === null) - (b === null) 
          || getDate(a) - getDate(b)
})
```

Here's a snippet:

```js
const array = [null, "2/1/2021", "1/1/2021", null, "3/1/2021"]

array.sort(
  (a, b) => (a === null) - (b === null)  || new Date(a) - new Date(b)
)

console.log(array)
```

Comment: nice

sorry, but

    const getDate = (value) => {
        const [day, month, year] = value.split('.');

        return Date.parse(`${month}.${day}.${year}`);
    }

Comment: @Denis what's the issue? It should work for this `getDate` function. (Assuming the string date values are in `DD/MM` format and not `MM/DD`)